# Why did Tyrion give the Lannister pendant to Ros?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 2, Cersei Lannister captures [Ros](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ros). Cersei mistakenly thinks that her brother Tyrion is secretly in love with Ros, because Ros wears a Lannister pendant. This mistake probably saved his real love, Shae, from Cersei.

I read that Tyrion gave this pendant to Ros when they were still in Winterfell. Is this true? Was this shown in the TV show? I can’t remember it.

If it’s true, why did Tyrion make this present? Could it be him foreseeing such a situation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tyrion did give the necklace to Ros, but we never actually see him do it. We know about it from another scene. When Ros and Theon Greyjoy are together she's wearing the necklace and tells him that it was a gift from Tyrion. As for why, Tyrion is usually very generous to the whores he beds, and he is extremely wealthy. A necklace of that sort wouldn't have meant much to him.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon it was just to piss Theon off, he knew she was a favourite of his, later Theon does say "I suppose gold's cheap for Lannisters" Ros then accuses him of being jealous which angers him further. It does sound like something Tyrion would do.